# Why pow function give me bad result?

Tags: c

I starting programming with language C and I have problem with using pow function.

I wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double result = 3 / 2 + 12 - (pow(5, 3) - 2)/6;
    double result2 = 3 / 2 + 12 - (5*5*5 - 2)/6;
    printf("%g %g", result, result2);
    return 0;
}
```

result has value -7.5, result 2 has value -7. I dont have any idea why its not equal.

Comment: `result2` is evaluated as `int`. `result` is as `double`, because `pow` returns `double`

Comment: Try `double result2 = 3 / 2 + 12 - ((double)5*5*5 - 2)/6;`

Comment: but result 2 is correct @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: but result 2 is correct @EugeneSh.

Comment: Because 3/2 is evaluated as integer as well and compensating that one half difference

Comment: `(pow(5, 3) - 2)/6` --> `(125.0 - 2)/6` --> `123.0/6` --> `20.5`

Comment: You are running into multiple integer division problems. `result` is `(3/2) == 1 + 12 - 20.5 = -7.5`. `result2` is `3/2) == 1 + 12 - 20 = 7` (right only by *Happy Accident*) To make `result` properly correct, `result = 3./2 + 12 - (pow(5, 3) - 2)/6;` (which is `-7` -- **note:** the `'.'` after `3`)

Comment: double result = (double)3 / 2 + 12 - (pow(5, 3) - 2)/(double)6;

is this correct version?

Comment: Short answer - YES. Using `3.` (or `3.0`) also ensures the constant `3` is of type `double`. But also note there are times when the mixing of integer math with floating-point math is **intentional**. So the "correct version" is the computation using the math your intended.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I am not sure if i corectly understand your second and third sentences.  Should i preffer "(double)" or "3." ?

Comment: In C, any numeric constant defaults to type `int`. So `3` is type `int` unless you change the default. Adding `3.` or `3.0` changes the type to `double` as does an explicit cast `(double)3`. So `3.` and `(double)3` are entirely equivalent.

Comment: See [C11 Standard - 6.4.4.1 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1) and [6.4.4.2 Floating constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2) (remember the C standard is written to guide compiler writers as much as it is written for programmers, do don't let the sometimes awkward wording bother you -- you will get used to it)

Comment: Ok, i understand. Thank you. Have a good time.